# how i get values from function

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

I want to set value to form input using function then POST the value. How can I do this?

**JS:**

```
function saveSignature() {
    $('#signature').empty();
    var dataUrl = $('.js-signature').jqSignature('getDataURL');

    $('#signature').append($('<p>').text(dataUrl));

    $('#data').jqSignature('getDataURL');
}
```

I tried to make it like this but it doesn't work.

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
    <input id="data" type="hidden" name="data" value="id='data'">
    <button id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-default" onclick="saveSignature();" disabled>Save Signature</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is `$('#signature')`? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: While, if your button is `disabled`, then how come `onclick` will work? It won't! [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vdmqqe04/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://api.jquery.com/val/ to modify the value of an input.

```
<script>

                    function saveSignature() {
                        $('#signature').empty();
                        var dataUrl = $('.js-signature').jqSignature('getDataURL');

                        $('#signature').append($('<p>').text(dataUrl));

                        $('#data').val(dataUrl);
                    }
</script>
```

Comment: how i can return dataUrl in <input> ??

Comment: i want to catch value from function and then display it at <input> to post it

Comment: `$('#data').val(dataUrl);` allow you to "display" dataUrl at <input> https://jsfiddle.net/b0c4fzd9/11/
return the value from the function won't help you

Answer (score -1):

```
function signature () {
    var somevalue = 'xyz';
    $(['name=data']).val(somevalue);
    ...
}
```